# Connection error: Request did not complete within rpc_timeout when doing cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I have installed Cassandra v2.0.16 on CentOS release 6.6 (Final).

But when I try to do cqlsh on it, It gives the following error,

**Connection error: Request did not complete within rpc_timeout**

On My local machine, I am running ubuntu 12.04, it works fine, but on my production machine (User Managed VPS running Cent OS) its not working properly.

I went to the /var/log/cassandra/system.log

```
ERROR [main] 2015-07-02 04:42:12,973 CassandraDaemon.java (line 571) Exception encountered during startup
org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: localhost/127.0.0.1:9042
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272)
    at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Server.run(Server.java:159)
    at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Server.start(Server.java:110)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.start(CassandraDaemon.java:489)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:567)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:643)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss$RegisterTask.run(NioServerBoss.java:193)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:366)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:290)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.run(NioServerBoss.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am just stuck here.

Please any help would be appreciated.

I am not getting how to solve this problem.

**Note: I have reinstalled Cassandra 2 to 3 times. But stuck with same problem**